# Storing SoapClient value in PHP session

Tags: php, session, cookies, soap-client

I want to store **SoapClient** return value in session but when i try to retrieve session value it doesn't show anything.

Here is my code to store value in session

```
<?php 
session_start();
$client = new SoapClient('https://portal.abc.com/API/DLCPMAPIServer.asmx?WSDL');
....
$response = $client->__soapCall("AddResult", array($params));
$_SESSION['casenum'] = $response ->AddResult->CaseNum;
```

Here I am trying to display the session in different page but it is not throwing session value

```
<?php print_r($_SESSION['casenum']); ?>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You should first `var_dump($response)` to see whether it is your expected result.

Comment: @Raptor thanks for your response. I have verified the session variable through var_dump and it is showing the session value.

Comment: wait. Did you use `session_start();` on different page before calling any `$_SESSION` variables?

Comment: @Raptor Yes. Also, if use this code <?php print_r($_SESSION); ?> then it loads other session but not this one.

Comment: In first PHP, what does `var_dump($response->AddResult->CaseNum)` return?

Comment: @Raptor, it returns "int(123455)". Actually it is returning the value successfully. And when i do that, vardump($_SESSION['casenum']) then still it writes the valid value in console through jquery.

Comment: I finally notice where the error is. As the value is an `int`, you shouldn't use `print_r()` to print it out (it's used for Arrays). Instead, you should simply use `echo $_SESSION['casenum'];`